# Windows 10 login fails at Samba NT domain member

Tags: domain, samba, samba4

I have the following setup:

- A Samba server **PDC** acting as the Primary Domain Controller of a NT domain **MYDOMAIN** (not Active Directory!)
- A Windows 10 pro PC **Win10** which is also a member of that domain
- A (new) second Samba server **MS1** which is supposed to be a member of that domain. It was added to that domain using the "/usr/bin/net join -U Administrator%Password" command and there was no error.
- There are no Windows servers involved.
- This is not a test installation but a production environment in a small company, so there are other Windows 10 PCs accessing **PDC** and simply changing the PDC configuration is not an option. (I'm what amounts for the network administrator for that company.)
- Samba version on both servers is 4.7.6-Ubuntu

With a given domain user account **MYUSER** I can log on fine to **Win10**. From there I can also access all the shares of **PDC**.

But the problem is: I cannot access any shares of **MS1**.

Windows explorer shows a logon dialog for the share and when I supply MYUSER and the password (again) it says "Access is denied".

On the command line "net use \\MS1\ShareName" results in the error "The password is invalid for \\MS1\ShareName", followed by a prompt for username and password for **MS1**. Entering **MYUSER** and the password the results in "System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied."

In the log on **MS1** for the IP of **Win10** I find the following entry:

```
[2021/12/09 13:57:41.755023,  0] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1259(check_account)
  check_account: Failed to convert SID S-1-5-21-2503006329-1497337827-313999797-1274
  to a UID (dom_user[MYDOMAIN\MYUSER])
```

Google found no match for this error message.

testparm on **MS1** gives me the following output:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[homes]"
NOTE: Service homes is flagged unavailable.
Processing section "[ShareName]"
Loaded services file OK.
idmap range not specified for domain '*'
ERROR: Invalid idmap range for domain *!

Server role: ROLE_DOMAIN_MEMBER
```

I tried to add an entry for idmap range but it did not make any difference.

I also tried to add **MYUSER** as a Linux user on MS1 with the same password as in the domain. It did not make any difference.

I'm at a loss on how to investigate this further. Which logs to look into and which configuration options to check.

Google turned up lots of hits but all of them were referring to an Active Directory installation. Unfortunately "simply" updating to ADS is not possible at the moment as that would possibly break other services.

Comment: After authenticating the user smbd needs to map the user to a local UID/GID, that is the purpose of identity mapping. Increase 'debug level = 10' and check for more details. grep `_Get_Pwnam` in smb log. If you see it fails in `check_account` function, then you most probably don't have working idmap, see idmap_<backend> man page (eg. 'rid', 'ad'...). See an example of failing idmap - https://gist.github.com/jirib/c5170a0ce75f28faef0943d481111375

Comment: Another question: what UID/GID should have your MYDOMAIN\myuser have? An autogenerated, an explicitly defined UID/GID a should it be mapped to a local Linux account?

Comment: @JiriB The original idea was to automatically also replicate the Linux users and use the same IDs. Unfortunately I have been taken off this project for now due to higher priority work, so it will take a while until I get back to this issue. I appreciate your input though. It might get a moot point because moving to AD now also became an option. I got a test installation (DC, SDC + MS) with AD running which seems to work for file serving, but there is still email to be considered.

Comment: Try to check SUSE KB article about various idmap backends pros/cons - https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017458